# How do i write the analytic function $f(z)$ in terms of $z$?

Tags: complex-analysis

```
I have an entire function, consider the function :
```

$f(z)= (3x^2 + 2x - 3y^2 - 1) + i(6xy + 2y)$

I want to write $f(z)$ in terms of $z$.

Comment: try rearranging by substituting $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z}=x-iy$. So, for example $z+\bar{z}=2x$ and $z \bar{z}=x^{2}-y^{2}$ etc

Answer (score 12):

If you have a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ that you want to write in terms of $z$, one thing you could do is substitute $x=(z+\overline z)/2$, $y=(z-\overline z)/2i$ and multiply everything out. If the thing is analytic in the first place all the $\overline z$'s should drop out.

For example

$$x^2-y^2++2ixy=\left(\frac{z+\overline z}{2}\right)^2
-\left(\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}\right)^2+2i\left(\frac{z+\overline z}{2}\right)\left(\frac{z-\overline z}{2i}\right)=\dots=z^2.$$

Comment: As a variation on this: Since $f(x,y)$ is a quadratic in $(x,y)$ and the above substitutions give polynomials in $(z,\overline{z})$, $f(z)$ must be quadratic in order to be entire. So all one needs to do is expand $az^2+bz+c$ and figure out what the coefficients must be.

Answer (score 5):

If you have already checked that function is indeed entire (e.g. using Cauchy-Riemann's equations), there is a clever trick finding $f$ as a function of $z$.

Take your expression, put $y=0$ and substitute $z$ for $x$. You will get
$$
f(z) = 3z^2 + 2z - 1.
$$

Why does this work? Let $g(z) = 3z^2 + 2z - 1$. Then $f$ and $g$ coincide on the the real axis (by construction) and $g$ is clearly entire. Thus, by the identity theorem for holomorphic functions, $f = g$ everywhere.

This method gives much shorter computations than substituting $x$ and $y$ by expressions in $z$ and $\bar z$, especially when the function is a little more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

$z^2 =  x^2 - y^2 + i 2xy\\
f(z) - 3z^2 = 2x -1 + i 2y\\
f(z) - 3z^2 - 2z = -1\\
f(z) = 3z^2 + 2z - 1$

Answer (score 0):

Let  $$f(z)= (3x^2 + 2x - 3y^2 - 1) + i(6xy + 2y)=u(x,y)+iv(x, y).$$
Then $$f'(z)=u_x+iv_x=6x+2+i6y =6(x+iy)+2=6z+2).$$
Now integrating w.r.t. z we get
$$f(z)=3z^2+2z+c.$$
You can find the value of $c$ to this particular problem!