# Polynomial division for identifying an expression in terms of complex numbers.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, complex-numbers

This question is blatantly copied from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800024/how-do-i-write-the-analytic-function-fz-in-terms-of-z), for the sake of learning more I specify it a bit more:

$$f(z)= (3x^2 + 2x - 3y^2 - 1) + i(6xy + 2y)$$

$$z = x+yi$$

I want to write $f(z)$ in terms of $z$ using **algebraic geometry** and a **division algorithm**. Is this possible?

Is it just to assume some monomial order and start dividing..? Or do I need to find a specific one that works or am I overthinking this? I'm OK with the question being marked as a duplicate and the answer written in the other question as long as I can get some feedback.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "algebraic geometry"? (and, don't you mean $z=x+yi$?).

Comment: Yes of course it's $z=x+yi$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry

Comment: The Cauchy-Riemann equations are a nice way to check if it's possible.

Comment: since $z = x \pmod y$ and $f(z) = 3x^2+2x-1 \pmod y$ you must have $f(z) = 3z^2+2z-1$ if it's a polynomial in $z$.

Comment: Of course, that didn't require very much algebraic geometry at all.

Comment: @StanCoreyCarter How come?

Comment: @mathreadler The equations are formulated to hold exactly when $\partial f/\partial\bar z=0$, which means $f$ is a function of $z$.

Comment: You mean a power series in $z$? I think I understand, that was a neat trick.